# Is there any built-in feature in firebase dynamic links to make it valid for a single use

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I want my generated Firebase dynamic links be usable just for one time.
After the first person used the link, we need to prevent the second use of that specific dynamic link.

Is there such a feature build in Firebase dynamic link ? or I should implement it manually inside my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Dynamics Links are designed to be useful to anyone who has the link.  There is no way to limit their usage.  That would be something you'd have to implement yourself with your own backend.